# javascript: recursion, method is defined, but it keeps on saying it's not defined

Tags: javascript, jasmine

**MergeSort.js**

```
var merge_sort = function(unsorted) {
  if (unsorted.length <= 1)
    return unsorted;

  var middle = unsorted.length / 2; 

  var left = unsorted.slice(0, middle - 1);
  var right = unsorted.slice(middle, unsorted - 1);

  left = merge_sort(left);
  right = merge_sort(right);

  return merge(left, right);
};

var merge = function(left, right) {
  var result = [];

  while(left.length > 0 || right.length > 0)
    if(left.length > 0 && right.length > 0) {
      if (left[0] <= right[0]) {
        result.push(left.shift());
      } else {
        result.push(right.shift());
      }
    } else if(left.length > 0) {
      result.push(left.shift());
    } else if(right.length > 0) {
      result.push(right.shift());
    }
  }

  return result;
};
```

**MergeSortSpec.js**

```
describe("#merge_sort", function() {

  it("should sort the unsorted array", function() {
    var unsorted = [8, 2, 10, 5, 4, 9, 7, 1, 6, 3];
    var sorted = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    expect(merge_sort(unsorted)).toEqual(sorted);
  });

});
```

**Error message**

```
ReferenceError: merge_sort is not defined
    at null.<anonymous> (file://localhost/Users/jasonkim/projects/algorithm-everyday/merge_sort/javascript/spec/MergeSortSpec.js:6:12)
```

I am not sure why jasmine.js is telling me that `merge_sort` is not defined. Even though it's there. Any idea why?

**SpecRunner.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="src/MergeSort.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/MergeSortSpec.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
      jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;

      var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();

      jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);

      jasmineEnv.specFilter = function(spec) {
        return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
      };

      var currentWindowOnload = window.onload;

      window.onload = function() {
        if (currentWindowOnload) {
          currentWindowOnload();
        }
        execJasmine();
      };

      function execJasmine() {
        jasmineEnv.execute();
      }

    })();
  </script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't look right, typo? `if left[0] <= right[0] {`

Comment: Yes, thank you for that. I fixed the typos. Same error thought. `ReferenceError: merge_sort is not defined`

Comment: Still not valid, `return result` is not in a function

Comment: Do you get any script errors in the console?

Comment: Other then that the code runs fine in http://http://tryjasmine.com/, beside the test fails cause the sort is not working properly. So it seems to be a problem with your test setup. Do you insert the script with the sort function before the test in your `runner.html`?

Comment: I added the SpecRunner.html now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is the missing opening bracket at the start of the `while` loop? If you fix that, it runs fine in jasmine (although the output is not correct)

```
var merge = function(left, right) {
    var result = [];

    while(left.length > 0 || right.length > 0) {
        if(left.length > 0 && right.length > 0) {
            if (left[0] <= right[0]) {
               result.push(left.shift());
            } else {
               result.push(right.shift());
            }
         } else if(left.length > 0) {
            result.push(left.shift());
         } else if(right.length > 0) {
            result.push(right.shift());
         }
     }

     return result;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I will have to fix the sort function as it is still not working right.